Nestjs Enviroment Variable is Undefined
I am trying to read the enviroment variable of nestjs in my db provider file but it keeps saying undefined
This is my db provider file
export const DataBaseProviders = [
    {
        provide: "DATA_SOURCE",
        useFactory: async (configService:ConfigService) => {
            const dataSource = new DataSource({
                type: configService.get<DB_TYPE>("DB_TYPE") as DB_TYPE,
                host: configService.get<string>("DB_HOST"),
                port: configService.get<number>("DB_PORT"),
                username: configService.get<string>("DB_USERNAME"),
                password: configService.get<string>("DB_PASSWORD"),
                database: configService.get<string>("DB_NAME"),
                entities: [
                    __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
                ],
                synchronize: true,
            });
            return dataSource.initialize()
        }
    }
];

but i keep getting this error
[Nest] 4712  - 07/27/2024, 11:30:04 AM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 4712  - 07/27/2024, 11:30:04 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at InstanceWrapper.useFactory (/Users/aon/Documents/CLIENT/streple/src/modules/database/database.providers.ts:11:37)

I have also added nestjs config in my app module
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({
    isGlobal: true
  }), AdminModule, DatabaseModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }

and i was expecting nestjs to automatically pass it down

There's no way to nestjs to automagically knows that you want to inject the ConfigService in that factory provider due to introspection limitations. That's why you need to tell that using the inject parameter.
So just add inject: [ConfigService]
You can catch those usage errors with this ESLint plugin: https://github.com/darraghoriordan/eslint-plugin-nestjs-typed/

Alright This was helpful, thanks
